# Using bootstrap grid system to place an image next to a div responsively

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the following html code to place an image next to div as in facebook comments:

```
  <div className="row">
      <div className="col-sm-1">
          <img
              className="img-thumbnail"
              src="image.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div className="col-sm-11">
          <div className="bg-light rounded p-1 pl-2">
              <span className="font-weight-bold text-primary">content</span>
              <div>
                  //buttons
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

However, this use of grid creates a space in the first div (`col-sm-1`) since the image size is smaller than the allotted width on the div. You can see the problem visually below. Any suggestions to mitigate this?

[image]

**UPDATE**

When using `col-sm-auto`, there is always a space left from the right because of `col-sm-11`, as you can see in the image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `col-sm-auto` instead of `col-sm-1` which will shrink the column to the width of the content (the image). Also remove the left or right padding on the columns.

https://www.codeply.com/go/SLirjy4KDw

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-auto pr-0">
            <img class="img-thumbnail" src="//placehold.it/40">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-11 pl-0">
            <div class="bg-light rounded p-1 pl-2">
                <span class="font-weight-bold text-primary">content</span>
                <div>
                    //buttons
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. It is almost perfect. This approach just leaves some space on the right hand since `col-sm-11` does not occupy all the width. Please see the update in the OP.

Comment: Then just change the `col-sm-11` to `col-sm` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use two div with d-inline as class. As these spaces will disappear

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/display/